# Possible NoSQL cases

Tags: python, nosql

There are two possible cases where I am finding MySQL and RDBMS too slow. I need a recommendation for a better alternative in terms of NOSQL.

1) I have an application that's saving tons of emails for later analysis. Email content is saved in a simple table with a couple of relations to another two tables. Columns are sender, recepient, content, headers, timestamp, etc.

Now that the records are a close to a million, it's taking longer to search through. Basically there are some pattern searches we are running.

Which would be the best free/open source NOSQL for replacement to store mails so that searching through them would be faster?

2) Another use case is fundamentally ann asset management library consisting of files. System very simplar to mails. Here we have files of all type of extensions. When the files are created or changed, we are storing meta data of the files in a table. Again data sizes have grown big over time, that searching them is not easy.

Ideas welcome. Someone suggested Mongo. Is there anything better and faster?

Comment: Unfortunately, this kind of question does not fit the format of this site, see the [FAQ#dontask]. Questions like these tend to lead to vague answers that are also outdated very quickly. If we can help you with a specific problem, feel free to post another question though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If search is your primary use case, I'd look into a search solution like ElasticSearch or Solr. Even if some databases support some sort of full text indexing, they're not optimized for this problem.